# How to print out data in three colums?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I want to print out a simple list of names from a mysql database into an html page that is using Bootstrap 3 css.

But rather than have one column with a long list I want to divide up the list in three columns ( on a desktop).

The code below does what I want but is not responsive. If I shrink the page all the names overlap. How can I print out the list in a responsive page (with three colums for desktop and perhaps two for mobile).

Thanks.

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT count(*) FROM mydatabase"); //Count Records
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

$x=0; //Create a counter to count records that have been echoed.
$num = $row[0];
$sum =($num)/3; //Divide the total number of records by 3

$sql = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT * FROM mydatabase"); //Get records
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  $x++; //Add 1 to counter


  echo $row['name']; //echo row

  echo "</br>";

if ($x>$sum){ //If the number of records already echoed is more than a third of the total then create a new column.
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<div class=\"col-sm-4\">";
  $x=0; //Reset counter
  }

} //End while loop
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Would you outline what _specific_ trouble you are having with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try like this code **100% working** and tested:

```
<?Php
    $connection = new mysqli('HOST_NAME', 'USER_NAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE_NAME');

    if ($connection->connect_errno > 0) {
        die ('Unable to connect to database [' . $connection->connect_error . ']');
    }   
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
    if (!$result = $connection->query($sql)) {
        die ('There was an error running query[' . $connection->error . ']');
    }   
?>

...

<?php
    $rows = $result->num_rows;    // Find total rows returned by database
    if($rows > 0) {
        $cols = 3;    // Define number of columns
        $counter = 1;     // Counter used to identify if we need to start or end a row
        $nbsp = $cols - ($rows % $cols);    // Calculate the number of blank columns

        $container_class = 'container-fluid';  // Parent container class name
        $row_class = 'row';    // Row class name
        $col_class = 'col-sm-4'; // Column class name

        echo '<div class="'.$container_class.'">';    // Container open
        while ($item = $result->fetch_array()) {
            if(($counter % $cols) == 1) {    // Check if it's new row
                echo '<div class="'.$row_class.'">';    // Start a new row
            }
                    $img = "http://yourdomain.com/assets/".$item['image_name'];
                    echo '<div class="'.$col_class.'">'.$img.'<h5>'.$item['name'].'</h5></div>';     // Column with content
            if(($counter % $cols) == 0) { // If it's last column in each row then counter remainder will be zero
                echo '</div>';   //  Close the row
            }
            $counter++;    // Increase the counter
        }
        $result->free();
        if($nbsp > 0) { // Adjustment to add unused column in last row if they exist
            for ($i = 0; $i < $nbsp; $i++)  { 
                echo '<div class="'.$col_class.'">&nbsp;</div>';        
            }
            echo '</div>';  // Close the row
        }
        echo '</div>';  // Close the container
    }
?>
```